# Is there a naming convention for angularjs views?

Tags: angularjs, naming-conventions

For example, I have `not found` html page. Should I name it

```
1. not-found.html
2. notFound.html
```

What's the file name convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not aware of a broadly adopted convention, I personally use camelCase, `notFound.html`. I like to do this across Angular files so `notFound.directive.html` for a template associated with a `notFound.directive.js` directive.

The one requirement in Angular to be aware of is that camelCased directive names need to be converted to "dashed" when referencing in HTML. So to reference the `notFound` directive in HTML you will need to reference `<not-found></not-found>`.

One resource that has helped me with regard to Angular conventions in general is John Papa's style guide, found [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md). Note that he actually suggests `not-found.html`, but again this specific case is up to personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [john papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#application-structure) angular style, it's not-found.html. But seriously, just choose the one that seems most natural to you :)